# Play Button Alignment Issues in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a header on the left side and want to add a button inline with the header on the right side.

When I add "position:relative: and top:400px, it moves the button perfectly. When i add "left:200px" it moves the button perfectly again, but when i hover it moves the button back to center of page.

How do i stop it from doing this?

i've created IMG images to show specifically how it moves: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMIO6.jpg

**note when left:200px; is not added, the button doesn't move to center of page. i've tried removing the "text-algin: center;" along with a lot of other ideas..but am stuck.

Here is the code: https://codepen.io/TheGreatEscape/pen/ebYgGO

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0vh;
}

.circle {
  stroke: #f70f4d;
  stroke-dasharray: 650;
  stroke-dashoffset: 650;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.playBut {
  position: relative;
  top: 400px;
  left: 200px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.playBut .triangle {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  stroke-dasharray: 240;
  stroke-dashoffset: 480;
  stroke: #000;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.playBut:hover .triangle {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  stroke: #f70f4d;
  animation: nudge 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes nudge {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(5px);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translateX(-2px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.playBut:hover .circle {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <a href='#' class='playBut'>

    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In  -->
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/" x="0px" y="0px" width="213.7px" height="213.7px" viewBox="0 0 213.7 213.7" enable-background="new 0 0 213.7 213.7"
      xml:space="preserve">
    
    <polygon class='triangle' id="XMLID_18_" fill="none" stroke-width="7" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
        73.5,62.5 148.5,105.8 73.5,149.1 "/>
      
    <circle class='circle' id="XMLID_17_" fill="none"  stroke-width="7" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="106.8" cy="106.8" r="103.3"/>
    </svg>


  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Chris and welcome to SO. Your question is a bit unclear and you do not include your header in your codepen so it's quite difficult to know what you want to achieve. On your codepen the play button doesn't move to the center of the page when I hover over it.

Comment: Try to provide a demo with your problem...

Comment: _“how do i provide a better demo that the pictures?”_ - [mcve] // The codepen does not seem to reproduce the issue. So showing us that image at most proves that you are not lying to us … but it doesn’t help in figuring out what goes wrong in the context of your actual page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this demo if it helps

```css
/*===== PLAY BUTTON ===*/

.container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
 margin-top: 0vh;
}

.circle {
  stroke: #f70f4d;
  stroke-dasharray: 650;
  stroke-dashoffset: 650;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.playBut {
 /*position: relative;
 top:400px;
 left:200px;*/
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.playBut .triangle {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  stroke-dasharray: 240;
  stroke-dashoffset: 480;
  stroke: #000;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.playBut:hover .triangle {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  stroke: #f70f4d;
  animation: nudge 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes nudge {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(5px);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translateX(-2px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
.playBut:hover .circle {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}


h2.title {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 60px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>

  <h2 class="title">some text</h2>
  
  <a href='#'class='playBut'>
    
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In  -->
<svg version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
     x="0px" y="0px" width="213.7px" height="213.7px" viewBox="0 0 213.7 213.7" enable-background="new 0 0 213.7 213.7"
     xml:space="preserve">

<polygon class='triangle' id="XMLID_18_" fill="none" stroke-width="7" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    73.5,62.5 148.5,105.8 73.5,149.1 "/>
  
<circle class='circle' id="XMLID_17_" fill="none"  stroke-width="7" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="106.8" cy="106.8" r="103.3"/>
</svg>


  </a>
</div>
```

**Update**
you need

```
a.playBut, a.playBut:hover, a.playBut:active, a.playBut:focus {
    left: 800px;
    right: auto;
}
```

see [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bvojbv)

normal
[image]

on hover
[image]

Comment: do you have any live demo that I can check ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: absolute` to your `.playBut`. `top` and `left` works only on absolute position.

[See example here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XombGE)